# Every docker image I make cannot bind to any port

Tags: docker

So I am trying to make an image, I have tried multiple ports, ports less than 1024 and ports greater, but all get the following error:

> 2018/11/21 15:34:34 listen tcp :9000: socket: permission denied

For this example, I'll use portainer. I have ran the following command with and without sudo:

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer
```

But I still get the error above. I have followed docker's post installation instructions;

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

ifconfig:

[image]

I have tried chmodding the docker.sock, but that doesn't work too, any ideas what or how I can fix this?

Comment: Please post text as text.

Comment: the number after the `:` should be the port used in the container: What port does the service listen on?

Comment: What images have you made?, please show docker file.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor as stated in the OP, I used portainer for the example, but no other images work for port binding too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing to digging around, with `dmesg | tail`

I got an error,

> apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" ....

Which was conflicting with my docker network, so I did the following to fix it:

Temporarily added

`deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main`

**to**

`/etc/apt/sources.list`

Then run

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install apparmor=2.12-4ubuntu5
```

Then removed `deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main` from sources. Now it's working. I'm not sure if this my docker version causing the problem, or my OS causing the issue, anyway, I'll report it to both